# Creating a condition so that the struct does not exceed 2GB (if it does, set it to null)?

Tags: python, pyspark

It appends new columns for each view's features. It creates a union of
    dataframes in following format:

```
            | uid         | all_features                                  |
            | XXXX-XXXX   |[{view1 => [F.struct]}, {view2 => [F.struct]]  |

df = None
for frame in dataframes:
    if not df:
        df = frame #  assign first dataframe to df
    else:
        df = df.join(frame, on="uid", how="outer")
df = df.select("uid", F.struct(
    [c for c in df.columns if c.lower() != 'uid']).alias("all_features"))
return df
```

I was hoping to make the value to be set to `null` if `[c for c in df.columns if c.lower() != 'uid']` exceeded 2GB (memory). Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, but it is (for me)  unclear what you are asking. Do you mean 2GB memory or is 2GB a value? Could please try to make your question more clear?

Comment: Memory. I have made the edit. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: You can use `df.memory_usage(index=True).sum()` to get the memory usage of a data frame, you can check this to see if usage is over 2 GB and if it is do `df = None`.